# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero in list elements division

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

Whenever I run this code I get the division by zero error in the mentioned lines below. Also, the error does not occur when the lists are not user inputs. How is the error coming and how can i fix it?

```
n=int(input("Dimension of the coefficient matrix: "))

a=[[0]*n]*n
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print("Enter (",i,",",j,") coefficient:")
        a[i][j]=float(input())

b=[float(input("Enter RHS :")) for i in range(n)]
'''
a=[
    [3,-2,5,0],
    [4,5,8,1],    ( not getting the error when the lists are not user input)
    [1,1,2,1],
    [2,7,6,5]
]
b=[2,4,5,7]
n=len(b)
'''

for k in range(n-1):
    for i in range(k+1,n):
        if a[i][k]==0: continue
        factor=a[k][k]/a[i][k]
        for j in range(k,n):
            a[i][j]=a[k][j]-a[i][j]*factor
        b[i]=b[k]-b[i]*factor

for i in range(n):
    print(a[i])

x=([(0)]*n)


x[n-1]=b[n-1]/a[n-1][n-1]  '''getting the error in this line'''

for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
    sum=0
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        sum+= a[i][j]*x[j]
    x[i]=b[i]-sum/a[i][i]  '''also in this line'''
for i in range(n):
    print("x(",i,") = ",x[i])
```

Comment: Your `a` matrix has zeros in it. Your example matrix has a zero in the first row, last element. You need to scrub your inputs a bit more thoroughly, particularly before division.

Comment: There is a if statement I used to bypass it in the code and the example matrix is not causing any trouble when written in the code . But when the matrix is taken as an user input then the error comes. @Adrien Keister

Comment: The only `if` statement I see protecting your code is `if a[i][k]==0: continue`, but that won't protect either of the two lines generating the errors. It only protects the next four lines, assuming the indentation in your question is correct. The indentation you have here shows that the lines `x[n-1]=b[n-1]/a[n-1][n-1]` and `x[i]=b[i]-sum/a[i][i]` are not protected by that `if` statement.

Comment: But in both the divisions, something is getting divided by a diagonal element and none of the diagonal elements will come zero in this code. @Adrien Keister

Comment: All I'm saying is that the ValueError you mentioned in your title indicates you're dividing by zero somewhere. I recommend you use some IDE like PyCharm to debug this code. Pause right before the offending line, for example, and investigate what's in memory.

Comment: I am using PyCharm but I am new to coding so I am not good at debugging yet.

Comment: Set a breakpoint right on the line `x=([(0)]*n)`. You do that by clicking to the left of the line. You should see a small red circle appear. Then, instead of clicking the green run arrow, just click the little bug-like button to the right of it. The code should pause at the breakpoint. Then you can use the calculator to see what values are in memory, and even modify them on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful @Adrian Keister

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way you create zero matrix: `a = [[0]*n]*n`. You just repeat `n` times the internal list `[0]*n`, but you don't copy it. So, you have `n` links to the same list. This is easy to understand with the following example:

```
In [1]: a = [[0]*2]*2

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

In [3]: a[1][1] = 1

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

You can do something like this: `a = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]`

Or just use `numpy` for more flexible works with array at all:

```
from numpy import zeros
a = zeros((n, n))
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. If I do a=[0]*2 is the 0 here also not getting copied ? That is, if after that I do a[0]=1, will a[1] automatically also be 1? I am new to coding.

Comment: No, in your example everything is fine. This is because `int` is immutable type, and `list` is mutable type. You can read more information about built-in types [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: So the immutable ones will be copied and the mutable ones will be linked?

Comment: Yes, you are right
This works the same way when you pass arguments to functions, so you need to be careful with that too